# Area of "Scalene" rectangles

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My friend told me that from antiquity land revenue officials compute area of "reasonably" rectangular ( diagonal no matter) fields to assess tax taking the opposite sides average as ..

$$ A = \dfrac{a+c}{2} \cdot \dfrac {b+d}{2} $$

What could be the (relative) error?

Comment: What does "reasonably" mean here? In general, there are infinitely many quadrilaterals with given side lengths $a, b, c, d$ (that together satisfy some obvious inequalities like $a < b + c + d$).

Comment: Don't know, I suppose corner angle differs from right angle by not more than 5 degrees.  People pay the tax, no questions asked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will approximate a "scalene" rectangle as a trapezium, that is a quadrilateral with two opposite sides which are parallel. I chose $a$ and $c$ as bases. Let's denote the angles adjacent to the greatest base $\alpha$ and $\beta$. We have that
$$\alpha = \frac\pi2 - \theta,\qquad\beta = \frac\pi2 - \phi,$$
where
$$\theta,\phi \in \left[0, \frac\pi{36}\right].$$
The area of the trapezium is therefore
$$A = \frac12(a + c)h = \frac12(a + c)b\sin\alpha = \frac12(a + c)d\sin\beta.$$
Let $A_0$ be the approximated area; then the relative error is
$$\delta A = \frac{A_0 - A}A = \frac{A_0}A - 1,$$
or
$$\begin{align}
\delta A &= \frac{(a + c)(b + d)}4\cdot\frac2{(a + c)b\sin\alpha} - 1 =\\[1.5ex]
&= \frac{b + d}{2b\sin\alpha} - 1 = \frac{b + b\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta}}{2b\sin\alpha} - 1 =\\[1.5ex]
&= \frac{\sin\alpha + \sin\beta}{2\sin\alpha\sin\beta} - 1 =\\[1.5ex]
&= \frac12(\sec\theta + \sec\phi - 2)
\end{align}$$

I don't know how to maximize this function only over the specified interval. However, with numerical methods, I computed the absolute maximum to be, approximately,
$$\delta A_{\text{max}} = 0.0038198375433473597,$$
which seems quite small. I would be glad if someone else verified my result.

Comment: The function is maximum at $\theta=\phi=\frac \pi{36}$ and at this point $\delta A_{\text{max}} =\sec \left(\frac{\pi }{36}\right)-1$ which is what you got (I maximized the function  over the specified interval).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Wow I feel so dumb. It was sufficient to look at the graph of $\sec x$ over that interval. The function is monotonically increasing there! Thank you for confirming the result though.

Comment: You are welcome ! I feel dumb too !